# Error al validar un request en laravel 7

Tags: laravel

Quiero insertar un nuevo registro en una tabla de mi bd y quiero hacer un validate a cada unos de los campos en el request pero no me funciona.

Esta es mi UserController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\User;
use App\Persona;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    
    public function registro(Request $request){

        $request->validate([
            'nombre'=> 'required',
            'apellidos'=> 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|email',
            'edad'=> 'required',
            'genero'=> 'required',
            'password'=> 'required',
        ]);

        $persona = new Persona;

        $persona->nombre = $request->input('nombre'); 
        $persona->apellidos = $request->input('apellidos'); 
        $persona->email = $request->input('email');
        $persona->edad = $request->input('edad');
        $persona->genero = $request->input('genero');
        
        if($persona->save()){

            $user = new User; 
            $user->persona_id = $persona->id;
            $user->name = $persona->nombre;
            $user->email = $persona->email;
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

            if($user->save()){
                return response()->json(["User"=>$user],201); 
            }
        } 

        return abort(400, "Error al registrar"); 
    }

}
```

y para ser uso de esto, utilizo mi ruta:

```
Route::post('/registro', 'UserController@registro');
```

utilizo insomnia para hacer la prueba, donde en el request que mando esta vacio y me da responde asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debería de mostrarme un error por que los campos son requeridos pero no.

Comment: Manda `Accept: application/json` en header, y mira que te devuelve.

Comment: No perdón si funciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Pero por que ocurre esto?

Comment: Te lo deje en respuestas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que Laravel detecte que lo que estas haciendo es una solicitud de api, te pide agregar como cabecera `Accept: application/json`, al agregar esto, laravel sabrá si arrojar 200, o un error 422.

Te recomendaría crear un middleware, en la cual forces a que se envie la cabecera, puede ser.

`php artisan make:middleware forceJsonHeader`

Lo editaríamos así:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Lo agregamos al `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'json.header' => \App\Http\Middleware\forceJsonHeader::class,
];
```

Ya solo tendrías que usarlo en tus rutas.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['json.header']], function () { ... });
```